# C++ DLL-Linking UnResolved Externals

Tags: c++, dllexport

I have a rather big `Core` project that I'm working with, I'm attempting to adapt it to use a DLL Engine I've built, I'm getting a bunch of errors like:

unresolved external symbol "private: static class

When including some of the headers from the Core in the DLL, the class is exported via __declspec(dllexport) but any header with static members throws out a crapload of errors regarding the static members.

This is a rather big project, I can't exactly run around removing every static class member I see, is there anyway around this kind of thing?

A basic example of a class that's being imported:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass
{
    public:
        static bool m_someVar;
}
```

For clarity sake I'd just like to address that m_someVar is defined/declared (forget the term) in the classes implementation file

Comment: Can you show us the _exact_ errors and preferably some corresponding code?

Comment: I added a basic class example, the error code is pretty much the same: 
5>MyFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static unsigned char MyClass::m_someVar" (?m_someVare@MyClass@@0EA)
(redressed with the above example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you compile the `Core` you want these functions to be `dllexport`; However, when you compile the DLL, you want them to be `dllimport`. In your case, you're always defining them as `dllexport`, thus when you link the DLL it complains that you've declared a function (and even said you'd export it) without ever defining it.

The solution is simple. Instead of manually `__declspec`ing, create a macro based on whether you're the `Core` or the DLL:

```
#ifndef I_AM_A_DLL
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#define IMPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
```

Use `EXPORT` for functions in the `Core`  and `IMPORT` for functions in external DLLs:

```
class EXPORT MyClass
{
    public:
        static bool m_someVar;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your snippet and running Dumpbin.exe /exports on the DLL produces this output:

```
1    0 0001107D ??4MyClass@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z = @ILT+120(??4MyClass@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z)
2    1 00017000 ?m_someVar@MyClass@@2_NA = ?m_someVar@MyClass@@2_NA (public: static bool MyClass::m_someVar)
```

Note how the export for the static member is there but has a subtly different name from yours.  If I run your export name through undname.exe, I get:

```
Undecoration of :- "?m_someVare@MyClass@@0EA"
is :- "private: static unsigned char MyClass::m_someVare"
```

Note the difference.  You've got an evil macro in your target project.  Fix your problem by adding this to the header file:

```
#undef bool
```

This might have some side-effects :)

Comment: Not really sure I follow, the macro used in my project is basically SOME_DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

Comment: @Undawned: no, it is a macro used in the target project.  Look for "#define bool unsigned char" in one of the header files.  That macro screws up your class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a silly question but are you defining it somewhere?  Your definition would look something like:

```
bool MyClass::m_someVar = false;
```